# Perform operation on destructured element in JS object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function capitalizeFirstLetter (string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1)
}
```

I want to capitalize the title after destructuring in one line,

```
const { question } = this.props
const {
  title,
  Question_uuid: questionUUID
} = question
```

How to capitalize property title after destructuring. ":" renames the variable and "=" assigns a default value.

Comment: Destructuring is just a way to unpack properties. You cannot perform any operation during destructuring. There are hacks like declaring another variable and providing a default value like `const { title, updatedTitle = title.toUpperCase() } = question` but that is unreadable and confusing

Comment: genuinely didn't see this comment before answering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destructuring is just a way to unpack values from objects and arrays. You cannot perform any action on the destructured values. You'd have to to do that in a separate line:

```js
let { title } = question;
title = capitalizeFirstLetter(title)
```

---

There are some hacks to make it happen while destructuring. (These are *purely academic* and **should not be used in an actual code base**)

One option is to create another variable and assign a [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2)

```
const { title, updatedTitle = capitalizeFirstLetter(title) } = question
```

This translates to

```js
var title = question.title,
    updatedTitle = question.updatedTitle === undefined 
                    ? capitalizeFirstLetter(title) 
                    : question.updatedTitle;
```

As you can see, this only works if the newly created variable name `updatedTitle` doesn't exist in `question` as a key.

---

There is another way to create a `title` variable without creating an extra variable. You could create a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) in `String.prototype` called `capitalize`. Destructure the `title` property from question to get the `capitalize` property

```js
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "capitalize", {
  get: function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1)
  }
});

const question = { title: 'lower case question' }
const { title: { capitalize: title } } = question

console.log(title)
```

This translates to:

```js
const title = question.title.capitalize;
```

The getter in `String.prototype` will be called and it will assign the *capitalized* string to the `title` variable.

Comment: neat solution but modifying native prototypes is, of course, a Bad Idea - maybe add something to that effect?

Comment: @WillJenkins I've mentioned that in bold :)

Comment: I see that but it looks like that that comment only refers to the second solution

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't change the original property but you can do this:

```
const {
  title,
  titleCap = capitalizeFirstLetter(title)
} = question
```

i.e. declare a 'dummy' variable that you provide a default value for. This would be a bad idea though - if at some point the value ever *did* exist in the original prop then your default value would be ignored.